# How to display another class in a gui class java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to create an employee payroll system. Im creating a dropdown menu with JMenuItem Add Employee, and when you click that menu item then it will display another jframe below to enter in all the employee details. I have the add employee JFrame made and it runs perfectly. So i was wondering how do link the two? This is a part of it that might help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Payroll");

        //create the Employee menu
        JMenu employee = new JMenu("Employee");
        employee.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        employee.add(new JMenuItem("Add"));
        final JMenuItem add = new JMenuItem();
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 if (add.isSelected()) {
                     JFrame f = new EmployeeTaxDetails1();
                     final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                             f.setVisible(true);
                                 frame.setVisible(false);

             }

        }});
```

Answer (score 1):

JInternal Frame is a frame within a frame in java so you should probably use [JInternalFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) 
You can learn how to use it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).